# Create animations like in candy crush in android

Tags: android, animation

How to create an animation like in candy crush, for example start animations as shown in [link](http://photos.1highscore.com/score20860_20150103163944.jpg). Then, they have popping button animations and start (particle exploding) animations as well. Any idea how implement such things in android. I tried the button expand animation like below, looks nothing like candy crush.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale=".98"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toYScale=".98"
        android:duration="900"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those animations are really complicated and you can't (Actually you can if you try really hard but wouldn't want to) make them without external libraries. Programming is mostly about using external libraries.

In this case, you want to find a graphics library/engine. A good example of this is OpenGL. You can do a lot of cool stuff with it, just read the documentation and you should know how to use the API.

However, if you really want to make the exact animations as CandyCrush, you probably can't. I guess CandyCrush must use some kind of private libraries owned by King (The company who created the game, not the actual king) to make the animations. Just explore OpenGL and you will find it very interesting.

Comment: *Programming is all about using external libraries.* that's a bold statement

Comment: Ok, changed it to mostly. @TimCastelijns But there are so less softwares that _doesn't_ use external libraries!

Comment: Lets say I want to color 3 stars based on the score (eg, 2 star, 3 star). Start with gray color and change the color of 1=>2=>3 starts to gold color. Do I still need libraries or can I use android simple stuff

Comment: @pats If you just want that you can create different images and set the image resource of image views however you like. Just 2 images is ok, one for a colored star and another for a grey star.

Answer (score 2):

As CandyCrush is a game, you can assume that the game is written using a graphics engine like OpenGL ES 2.0 or jMonkeyEngine. Those libaries are used to generate dynamic 2D and 3D content.
I am sure that CandyCrush does not use standart android templates for animation or displaying text.

If you want to implement those animations I think you have to learn OpenGL ES 2.0 or any other 3D/2D Libary.

Edit: 
Here are some links to start:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

http://www.jayway.com/2013/05/09/opengl-es-2-0-tutorial-for-android-part-i-getting-started/

http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html